# How to call bootstrap modal dialog from SSJS in XPages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Edit I added this after the

```
</xp:this.action>
```

and it appeared to work a couple times, but now it has quit. So don't know if I have a solution or not:
Further edit make sure you have the two xp:attr 's or it does not work.

```
<xp:this.onComplete>
    var id = "#{id:panelModal}"
    XSP.partialRefreshGet(id,{
    onComplete: function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
        });
</xp:this.onComplete>
```

I have created the test code below to call -- if I comment out the link and show the button the modal window displays correctly. However, when I set the attrs for toggle-data and toggle-target I can't get the modal to display.

```
<xp:panel id="panelMain">
        <xp:link text="Create Document" id="buttonLink1" styleClass="btn btn-default">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal">
                </xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="data-target" value="createDialog">
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Do some stuff here"}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:link>


<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#createDialog"> Search
        </button>
-->
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="createDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            <xp:label id="label1">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Search " + appProps[sessionScope.ssApplication].appDesc}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
      </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xp:panel><!-- panel main -->
```

Comment: I post my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35890360/1960931 May be it is help for you

Answer (score 1):

So here is the code that works. May be some refinements that can be made but it works. If you have suggestions on improving this please feel free

```
<xp:panel id="panelMain">
        <xp:link text="Create Document" id="buttonLink1" styleClass="btn btn-default">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal">
                </xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="data-target" value="createDialog">
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Do some stuff here"}]]></xp:this.action>
<xp:this.onComplete>
    var id = "#{id:panelModal}"
    XSP.partialRefreshGet(id,{
    onComplete: function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }});
</xp:this.onComplete>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:link>


<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#createDialog"> Search
        </button>
-->
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="createDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            <xp:label id="label1">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Search " + appProps[sessionScope.ssApplication].appDesc}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
      </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xp:panel><!-- panel main -->
```

Comment: Why not just view.postcript("$('.modal').modal('show')")?  Works fine for me.